# Google MAP Geolocation API in PHP

Tags: php, google-maps

I call the Google MAP Geolocation API in PHP, to get the location by the cellTower information. However, when I change any of the cellTower information, I always get the same results: { "location": { "lat": 52.519171, "lng": 13.406091 }, "accuracy": 18000.0 }.

Here is my PHP script, could anyone help to check where is the problem? Thank you.

```
    <?php
    // The data to Google API
    $JsonData = array(
        'CellTowers' => array (
    'cellId' => 42,
    'locationAreaCode' => 415,
    'mobileCountryCode' => 310,
    'mobileNetworkCode' => 410
    ));

    // Create the context for the request
    $context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => "Content-Type: application/json\r\n",
        'content' => json_encode($JsonData)
    )
    ));

    // Send the request
    $response = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=', FALSE, $context);

    // Check for errors
    if($response === FALSE){
        die('Error');
    }

    echo $response;
    ?>
```

Comment: Just an observation, shouldn't be cellTowers instead of CellTowers? I think its case sensitive.

Comment: The problem is the JSON data, it works when changed to following:$cellData = array(
    'cellTowers' => array (
     array ('cellId' => $CELL,
         'locationAreaCode' => $LAC,
            'mobileCountryCode' => $MCC,
            'mobileNetworkCode' => $MNC)
));

Comment: Thank you, keepwalking. Yes, it is case sensitive and it should be cellTowers.

Comment: Your welcome, please mark my comment as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the JSON data, it works when changed the $cellData to following:

```
    $cellData = array(
        'cellTowers' => array (
        array ('cellId' => 42,
           'locationAreaCode' => 415,
           'mobileCountryCode' => 310,
           'mobileNetworkCode' => 410)
    ));
```